# How to change the database name display in django admin site?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is it possible to change change the database name in django admin site?

Just like how I change the  following:

> admin.site.site_header = "Administrator"
>
> admin.site.site_title = "Administrator"
>
> admin.site.index_title = "Admin"

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options, you can do it manually, or you can do it through the help of an external python library

### Manually

is by creating custom [AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-attributes)

#### admin.py

```py
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    # Text to put at the end of each page's <title>.
    site_title = ugettext_lazy('My site admin')

    # Text to put in each page's <h1> (and above login form).
    site_header = ugettext_lazy('My administration')

    # Text to put at the top of the admin index page.
    index_title = ugettext_lazy('Site administration')

admin_site = MyAdminSite()
```

#### urls.py

```py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include
from myproject.admin import admin_site

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin_site.urls)),
)
```

---

### by using python package

you can use the python package called [django-admin-interface](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-interface/)

```bash
pip install django-admin-interface
```

you'll need to import it into your `settings.py`

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #...
    "admin_interface",
    "flat_responsive", # only if django version < 2.0
    "flat", # only if django version < 1.9
    "colorfield",
    #...
    "django.contrib.admin",
    #...
)

# only if django version >= 3.0
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "SAMEORIGIN"
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ["security.W019"]
```

after installing it, you'll be able to customize your admin panel from the themes menu inside your admin panel

[image]

---

You can change the app name by adding `verbose_name` under app.py

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PharmacyConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'pharmacy'
    verbose_name = 'Your Home Page'
```

Comment: How about the database label display in admin site? how can i change it?

Comment: @ClaireAnnVargas you mean the `PHARMACY` variable?

Comment: yes the PHARMACY

Comment: @ClaireAnnVargas it's called app name I updated the answer